# Convention in physics for [],{} and operators (QM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, operators, notation, conventions

I got a little mixed up with the convention in physics.

Usually a hat means an operator. For a given electron-ion Hamiltonian 
$\hat{H}_{e-n}$, what are the difference between these:

1) $\hat{H}_{e-n}[{\bf{R}}]$

2) $\hat{H}_{e-n}[{\bf{R}}](\bf{r})$

3) $\hat{H}_{e-n}[{\{\bf{R}}\}]$

4) $\hat{H}_{e-n}[{\{\bf{R}}\}](\bf{r})$,

5) $H_{e-n}[{\{\bf{\hat{R}}}\}](\bf{\hat{r}})$,

with $\bf{R}$ the position of the nucleii and $\bf{r}$ the position of the electrons.

From what I know, I think $[\bf{R}]$ means a parametric dependence on the ionic position (i.e. given some atomic position you can apply the operator and it does not explicitely depends on atomic position).

For the curl bracket $\{\bf{R}\}$ I think it means that you cycle over all possible type of atomic position?

Also, what is the difference between putting the hat on the operator H and on the positions knowing that the position operator resolve itself by:

$\bf{r} = <0|\hat{r}|0>?$

EDIT:
Something more traditional is the notation for the exchange-correlation functional

$V_{xc}[\rho](\mathbf{r})$

Comment: Where did you find the notations like these 1-5? I've never seen such, and I'm not novice in QM. Please provide the reference to your source.

Comment: The closest thing I've seen to using $\{ \bf{R} \}$ is when one wants to write that $\bf{R}$ is the set of all $\{\bf{R_i} \}$. For instance, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation

Comment: $r$ is a c-number, $\hat{r}$ is a q-number (operator) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-number), though in literature people often omit the "hat".

Comment: Just a comment because I have no idea what `{}` means. (1) -> (2) and (3) -> (4) is just the difference between a function and a function evaluated at a given input. (4) is an operator-valued (hat on $H$) function depending on non-operator parameter $\{R\}$, applied to $r$; contrast this with (5), which is takes operators as parameters (hat on $\{R\}$) and inputs (hat on $r$) and is either a scalar value (no hat on $H$) or inherits its value from its inputs (think programming in languages with malleable typing rules).

Comment: The notation are from an unpublished paper. I now understand a little bit better. What is very usual though is V_xc[\rho](r). In that case why does the exchange-correlation potential depends functionally on the density and in a variable way on r?

Comment: Which unpublished paper?